# WinForms Canvas KeyDown event not fired

Tags: winforms, events, canvas, keydown

Canvas KeyDown Event not working
I have set KeyPreviou on my form to true.
I have set canvas Focusable to true.
I Focus on my canvas control when Mouse is pressed
Any info on this matter did not help me.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found what the problem was. I posti it so others will benefit.
Initially i focused on my canvas inside the **MouseDown** event.
Now i focused on the canvas inside the **MouseUp** event and all working ok.